# c programming, data structure in c book, confusion

Tags: c, data-structures

i mostly code in python. i have 0 experience in c. I bought a book on data structure in c, because I wanted to learn a low-level language and algorithms, i was told "data structure in c by noel kali charan" was a good beginner book,

i have downloaded codeblock and set it up correctly. i have been going through the book, following along with the code they provide

this is what the book has, and it has given me so many errors. so i did my research, thinking maybe the book is outdated(published 2015)
i expect my errors to be in the syntax.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>



typedef struct date{
    int day;
    char month[4];
    int year;
}Date;


Date dob, borrowed, returned;

dob.day = 15;
strcpy(dob.month, 'nov');
dob.year =2015;


void printDate (Date d){
    printf("%s %d %d \n", d.month, d.day, d.year);

}

printDate(dob);
```

i ended up here, no errors , but the print f method wont work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>



typedef struct date{
    int day;
    char month[4];
    int year;
}Date;
int main() {


Date dob, borrowed, returned;

dob.day = 15;
strcpy(dob.month, 'nov');
dob.year =2015;

void printDate (Date d){
    printf("%s %d %d \n", d.month, d.day, d.year);

}
printDate(dob);

return 0;
}
printDate(dob);
```

my question::

-is this book outdated? 
-any advice on starting with c, i would like to learn the rules of the syntax 
but i haven't been able to find beginners guide to learn from,

thanks

Comment: I'd bet dollars to donuts that the code you posted here is not what's in the book, and that all of the errors come from the differences.

Comment: Define "won't work" - are you not getting any output at all, are you getting output you don't expect, or something else?

Comment: its snippets rather than full files. do you have experience with this book?

Comment: one of the error is expected '=', 'v',';', 'asm'

Comment: `strcpy(dob.month, 'nov')` is this how it's in the book?

Comment: the code posted is incomplete, for example, no `main()` function; code hanging outside function. Did you perhaps forget any source code lines? Also strings in C must be delimited by double quotes and you used single quotes above. Did the book have single quotes oeiginally (or you have been trying stuff on your own)?

Comment: You can't define `printDate` within the body of the `main` function - it must be defined outside of `main`.

Comment: the first code is word by word from the book the second is me trying  to make it work . and yes the book has double quotes, i didn't know it was important

Comment: If your first code block has `strcpy(dob.month, 'nov')`, but the book used double quotes, then it's not word-for-word from the book.

Comment: yeah your right i thought they could be used interchangeably like in python, but that was a bad assumption. I'm starting to see c is a much more strict language

Comment: Your stated question is whether or not the book is trustworthy, which is largely opinion-based (except in the more extreme/blatant cases). You probably should retool your question to focus on resolving the errors to better fit the Stack Overflow model.

Comment: but forgive me about my question, I was wondering, before learning structs and functions did you learn about the data types `c` has?

Comment: no, this book is my first introduction to c programming. should I start in data types? I bought the book to study mostly algorithms, but I later decided that it would be more productive to learn c whiles learning algorithms(2 birds one stone )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you mean to write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct date{
  int day;
  char month[4];
  int year;
} Date;

Date dob, borrowed, returned;

void printDate (Date d){
  printf("%s %d %d \n", d.month, d.day, d.year);
}

int main() {
  dob.day = 15;
  strcpy(dob.month, "nov");
  dob.year = 2015;
  printDate(dob);
}
```

instead, because in your code I see no include for the `string` header file to use `strcpy`, 'nov' which is a string and then need to be `"nov"` instead becuase c is not Python

Comment: that works, im starting to see the syntax of the language